# how to insert php variable in js script

Tags: javascript, php

I have this js script. Instead of "2175" I'd need to insert here a certain $x php variable. How do I go about that?

```
var options = {
useEasing : true, 
useGrouping : true, 
separator : ',', 
decimal : '.' ,
prefix : '' ,
suffix : '' 
}
var demo = new countUp("myTargetElement", 0, 2175, 0, 2.5, options);
demo.start();
```

Comment: var demo = new countUp("myTargetElement", 0,<?php echo "2175" ?>, 0, 2.5, options); or you can use ajax

Comment: Not working I'm afraid, I need $x variable to be inserted, please be more specific about how to achieve it using ajax

Comment: Ok I figured it out: counter = '<?php echo $x ;?>';

var options = {
useEasing : true, 
useGrouping : true, 
separator : ',', 
decimal : '.' ,
prefix : '' ,
suffix : '' 
}
var demo = new countUp("myTargetElement", 0, counter, 0, 2.5, options);
demo.start();